# Java: when/how to call a setter from constructor and GSON deserializer

Tags: java, json, gson, deserialization

I am serializing/deserializing the following class:

```
public class Branch {

     private Conditional condition;
     private transient StringProperty conditionText = new SimpleStringProperty();

     public Branch()
     {
     }

     public Branch(Conditional condition) {
         this();
         setCondition(condition);
     }

     public void setCondition(Conditional condition) { 
         this.condition = condition;
         if (this.condition != null) {
            conditionText.set(this.condition.toString());
         } else {
             conditionText.set("");
         }
     }
}
```

`Conditional` is a class I've written.  `Branch` has other properties and methods that I've omitted for clarity.

The purpose of `conditionText` is just to provide the result of `condition.toString()` whenever the GUI needs it (which is why it's a `StringProperty`).  The value of `conditionText` is updated in the setter for `condition`.  So in theory every time `condition` changes, `conditionText` is updated appropriately.

Note that the constructor also calls `setCondition()` so that `conditionText` is set at the time the `Branch` is constructed.  [ Side question: I've heard calling a setter from a constructor is bad practice, but does it not make sense in this type of scenario? ]

When I deserialize `Branch` using the default GSON deserializer, everything goes as expected.  However, the problem I am running into is that the setter for `condition` is apparently never called during deserialization and so the value of `conditionText` is never set.

Is there a way to fix this, or a better way of doing it, such that `conditionText` is updated whenever `condition` is updated, even during GSON deserialization?

I can imagine a couple of possible approaches but I'm not sure either is the best:

1. Make `Condition` an `Observable` class and add a `ChangeListener` to
   `condition`  that updates `conditionText`
2. Write a custom deserializer for `Branch` that just invokes the default deserializer on every property of `Branch` and then invokes the constructor for `Branch`

Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: If you call setCondition, ever (not just from the constructor) you should always get a null pointer exception because nothing is initializing the contictionText variable, which means it is null.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to include the call to the `SimpleStringProperty` constructor.  That was already in my original source code, so it was not the cause of my problem.  I've now added the constructor call here, too.

Comment: As far as I know, the only problem with calling a setter from a constructor is the possibility of your setter being overridden and therefore doing something you don't expect. Not a problem if the class is final or the setter is final.

Answer (score 0):

The approach I ended up taking was #2 above.

I wrote a custom deserializer for Branch.  All it does is call the context's deserializer for every element of Branch, each of which is stored in a local variable.  Then I invoke the constructor for Branch, passing in the locally stored variables, and return the result.